# What is the right way to adding extra fields in laravel-spatie package?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-permission

1 Days ago I start try to learning how to use laravel spatie package, but right now i'm little bit confuse what is the right way to adding extra fields in spatie pacakage. I try following documentation from spatie web to extends the models and here's my code.

Migration schema

```
Schema::create($tableNames['roles'], function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('guard_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Override Models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as SpatieRole;

class Role extends SpatieRole
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->mergeFillable(['color', 'description']);
    }
}
```

Controller Testing

```
class RoleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $role = Role::where('name', 'Super Admin')->first();
        $roleAdmin = Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first();

        if (!$role) {
            Role::create([
                'name' => 'Super Admin',
                'color' => 'Black',
                'description' => 'Manage all the role and permission in the system'
            ]);
        }
        if (!$roleAdmin) {
            Role::create([
                'name' => 'Admin',
                'color' => 'Red',
                'description' => 'Manage users in the system'
            ]);
        }
        return Role::paginate(20);
    }
```

my code working fine right now, but i really wanted to know if im doing mistake or there is better way. in general i'm still new with php and laravel, thanks alot~

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you need to create roles table? It's better to extend rather recreate a table, this is in case Package makes changes to the core migration.

```
        Schema::table($tableNames['roles'], function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('description');
        });
```

Also, if you are to have few attributes like above it would be even better to add a separate table for those attribute.

2. I am not sure on why you are adding new roles in the `index()` method, I assume for testing. If it's for testing, I would suggest refactoring code to the following:

```
$roles = [[
    'name' => 'Super Admin',
    'color' => 'Black',
    'description' => 'Manage all the role and permission in the system'
], [
    'name' => 'Admin',
    'color' => 'Red',
    'description' => 'Manage users in the system'
]];

foreach($roles as $role) {
    Role::firstOrCreate($role);
}

return new RoleResource::collection(Role::all());
```

You would want to use Laravel Seeders to seed roles first. Also, If you are to have only few roles than you probably have no need for `paginate()` method.

Comment: thank's alot answering question.

1. yes i'm not recreate table my self, i'm just following where schema was created by default from command and then i adding some extra field right there.
at this step i still don't know if this is the right way to do after that.

2. yes i created just for testing purpose, oh i see i will noted that always make in seeders class.

once again thank's alot~